# Running Scrapy spider as script doesn't get all the code, but scrapy spider from project does

Tags: javascript, python, scrapy

I have a simple spider which scrapes a couple things from a script on a page.

I scrape the script as such

```
jsData = json.loads(response.xpath('//script[@type="application/ld+json"]//text()').extract_first())
```

When i run this in my spider from a project, I get all the data, but if I run it from a regular script, not in a project, it doesn't get everything from the script. Why is that?

This is my script spider

```
import scrapy
import json
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess


class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "target"
    start_urls = ['https://www.target.com/p/madden-nfl-22-xbox-one-series-x/-/A-83744898#lnk=sametab']

    def parse(self, response):
        jsData = json.loads(response.xpath('//script[@type="application/ld+json"]//text()').extract_first())
        NAME_SELECTOR = jsData['@graph'][0]

        yield {
            'name': NAME_SELECTOR,
        }


process = CrawlerProcess()

process.crawl(MySpider)
process.start()
```

It gives me

```
...'offers': {'@type': 'Offer', 'priceCurrency': 'USD', 'availability': 'InStock', 'availableDeliveryMethod': 'ParcelService', 'potentialAction': {'@type': 'BuyAction'}, 'url': 'https://www.target.com/p/madden-nfl-22-xbox-one-series-x/-/A-83744898'}}}
```

My project spiders code is

```
import scrapy
import json

class targetSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "target"
    start_urls = ['https://www.target.com/p/madden-nfl-22-xbox-one-series-x/-/A-83744898#lnk=sametab']

    def parse(self, response):
        jsData = json.loads(response.xpath('//script[@type="application/ld+json"]//text()').extract_first())
        test = jsData['@graph'][0]

        yield {
            'test': test
        }
```

It gives me

```
...'offers': {'@type': 'Offer', 'price': '59.99', 'priceCurrency': 'USD', 'availability': 'PreOrder', 'availableDeliveryMethod': 'ParcelService', 'potentialAction': {'@type': 'BuyAction'}, 'url': 'https://www.target.com/p/madden-nfl-22-xbox-one-series-x/-/A-8
3744898'}}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's about javascript. Content like `'price': '59.99'` is loaded by javascript. And `Downloader` in Scrapy doesn't support running javascript by default.

Possible causes for your problem

- One of your spider has `settings.py` enabled some external downloader middlewares (like Selenium, Splash, Playwright), and the other doesn't.
- The script starting spider with `CrawlerProcess()`, is not running under the project root, which causes `settings.py` failed to be loaded.

Update: Sorry, I forgot that we need to load settings manually when using `CrawlerProcess()`. [Run scrapy from a script](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#run-scrapy-from-a-script).

Comment: importing `from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings` and adding `get_project_settings()` into my `CrawlerProcess()` fixed the issue. Thanks!